# How to display data in grid without wrapping the data?

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid control which is bound to a `DataTable`. I'm facing a problem in the display of data. Though each line in `DataColumn` of grid having enough space yet the data is being wrapped to next subsequent lines. But I need the data to be displayed without wrapping. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in every field that you do not wish to wrap data.

```
ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
```

Comment: ItemStyle-Wrap="false" exactly solved my issue... thanx a lot :)

Comment: Even when I give Wrap="true" i didn't find any difference. Is there any other solution for this? pls help thanx :)

Comment: It is working fine if there is no space between the data. Is wrapping possible even there is space between data.pls help thanx :)

Comment: @aparnalarthik can you please give here a little code to see whats wrong ? Maybe is not the ItemStyle-Warp but other Warp... there is 2-3 warp, check them out.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation" ItemStyle-Width = "10px"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" temStyle-Wrap="false"><ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("designation") %>'/></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

Comment: For example "12:00AM-12:15AM" is displayed without wrapping but if i give space(like this "12:00 AM - 12:15 AM" inbetween it is not working... pls help thanx :)

Comment: @aparnakarhik Remove the  ItemStyle-Width = "10px" , check the temStyle-Wrap="false" must be. ItemStyle-Wrap="false"

Comment: As you told ItemStyle-Wrap is working when the requirement is for one particular column.I need it for all the columns... I included (white-space:nowrap)this in my css class and included this classfile to all columns of my Template fields. It is working :-)